# Setting default character encoding and content type in embedded Jetty

Tags: java, servlets, kotlin, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm making a DSL for embedded Jetty, and I'm having trouble setting `characterEncoding` and `contentType`. I want the users to be able to specify default values for these two fields, but Jetty is making life hard.

`res.characterEncoding = null` gives `res.characterEncoding` the value `iso-8859-1`.

`res.characterEncoding = ""`, gives `res.characterEncoding` the value `""`, but `res.contentType` becomes `application/json;charset=`

`res.characterEncoding = ""` THEN `res.characterEncoding = null` has the same effect as just doing `res.characterEncoding = ""`

I ended up with a ridiculous code snippet based on this odd behavior:

```
if (res.characterEncoding.contains(";javalin-default") || res.contentType.contains(";javalin-default")) {
    res.contentType = res.contentType.replace(";javalin-default", "")
    res.characterEncoding = null
    if (res.contentType.contains("application/json")) {
        res.contentType = "application/json"
    } else {
        res.characterEncoding = defaultCharacterEncoding
    }
}
```

But that can't be the right thing to do. Any ideas?

I have an issue for it here: https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/issues/259

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are fighting an overly complex aspect of the Servlet spec.

> *Opinion: The `HttpServletResponse.setContentType(String)` method should never have existed, it should have just been `.setMimeType(String)` and `.setCharacterEncoding(Charset)`*

Lets start with how character encoding is important.

When `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` is accessed, the implementation must resolve the response character encoding and locale to use for the created `PrintWriter`.  This means that the character encoding at this point will have a value assigned.

Notice that the locale is used too, this is often overlooked, but since you are a library writer, this should be pointed out to you.  See `HttpServletResponse.setLocale(Locale)` and `HttpServletResponse.getLocale()`.

Something else to consider is that if you have accessed `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` already, then the use of `HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding(String)` later results in a no-op, and using `HttpServletResponse.setContentType(String)` with a `charset` can result in the `charset` being stripped from the header produced. (again, this is in line with Servlet spec behavior).

The `HttpServletResponse.getCharacterEncoding()` can return the character encoding if manually set to a valid value earlier, or based on the `Content-Type` if already declared, otherwise it defaults to ISO-8859-1.  If it is using the `Content-Type` it first checks for `charset` parameter and uses it.  If `Content-Type` does not have `charset`, then it uses the `mime-type` configuration in your web metadata. This call should never produce an empty or null character encoding.

Servlet Spec default for use of `HttpServletResponse.getCharacterEncoding()` is `ISO-8859-1` (this value is taken from RFC2616, when this aspect of the Servlet spec was defined).

The web metadata comes from the web descriptor (aka the `WEB-INF/web.xml`), default descriptor, override descriptor, `org/eclipse/jetty/http/mime.properties` resource, `org/eclipse/jetty/http/encoding.properties`, other features present (such as `GzipHandler`) and programmatic configurations.

In Jetty, all of these various configuration sources for mime-type result in a configured Jetty `org.eclipse.jetty.http.MimeTypes` object.

When `HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding(String)` is called, it also has the responsibility to modify the `Content-Type` field and header on the response.

Assuming that `.getWriter()` hasn't been called yet, using `setCharacterEncoding(null)` will remove any existing `charset` parameter on `Content-Type` field and header.  `setCharacterEncoding("utf-8")` would add/change the `charset` parameter to `utf-8` on the `Content-Type` field and header.

When `HttpServletResponse.setContentType(String)` is called, it also has the responsibility to modify the Character Encoding field if a `charset` parameter was provided.

Knowing all this, you'll realize that you have to be careful of the order of the various API calls, in particular when the `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` call is made.

Instead of using the Servlet HttpServletResponse APIs to manage this, you should perhaps be controlling this via the web metadata for `application/json` on startup of the webapp.

In your case, you'd just configure the `MimeTypes` on the `ServletContextHandler` that your `JettyServerUtil.kt` is creating, no need for any of the hacks you are using.

Default behavior of Jetty's `ServletContextHandler` and `MimeTypes` configuration will not add the charset, due to how `application/json` is defined in the `org/eclipse/jetty/http/encoding.properties` resource (as an assumed charset).

Example:

```java
package jetty;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.IO;

public class MimeTypeJsonExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(9090);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.addServlet(JsonServlet.class, "/demo");
        context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/"); // handle static content and errors for this context
        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.addHandler(context);
        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler()); // handle non-context errors
        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();

        try
        {
            demonstrateJsonBehavior(server.getURI().resolve("/"));
        }
        finally
        {
            server.stop();
        }
    }

    private static void demonstrateJsonBehavior(URI serverBaseUri) throws IOException
    {
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) serverBaseUri.resolve("/demo").toURL().openConnection();
        dumpRequestResponse(http);
        System.out.println();
        try (InputStream in = http.getInputStream())
        {
            System.out.println(IO.toString(in, UTF_8));
        }
    }

    private static void dumpRequestResponse(HttpURLConnection http) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.printf("%s %s HTTP/1.1%n", http.getRequestMethod(), http.getURL());
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.printf("%s%n", http.getHeaderField(null));
        http.getHeaderFields().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() != null)
                .forEach((entry) -> System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", entry.getKey(), http.getHeaderField(entry.getKey())));
    }

    public static class JsonServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            resp.setContentType("application/json");
            PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
            resp.setHeader("X-Charset", resp.getCharacterEncoding());
            writer.println("{\"mode\":[\"a=b\"],\"animals\":[[\"kiwi bird\",\"kea\",\"skink\"]]}");
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the output ...

```
2018-06-27 09:00:32.754:INFO::main: Logging initialized @360ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2018-06-27 09:00:32.898:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.11.v20180605; built: 2018-06-05T18:24:03.829Z; git: d5fc0523cfa96bfebfbda19606cad384d772f04c; jvm 9.0.4+11
2018-06-27 09:00:32.969:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5dd6264{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2018-06-27 09:00:33.150:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@60707857{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9090}
2018-06-27 09:00:33.151:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @764ms

----
GET http://192.168.0.119:9090/demo HTTP/1.1
----
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Jetty(9.4.11.v20180605)
X-Charset: utf-8
Content-Length: 58
Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 14:00:33 GMT
Content-Type: application/json

{"mode":["a=b"],"animals":[["kiwi bird","kea","skink"]]}

2018-06-27 09:00:33.276:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Stopped ServerConnector@60707857{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9090}
2018-06-27 09:00:33.278:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5dd6264{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
```

As you can see, the `JsonServlet` only set the `Content-Type` mime-type, accessed the `PrintWriter`, set a header `X-Charset` to show the current character encoding value, and then wrote the json content.

The `Content-Type` response header seen by the client does not include the assumed `charset` of `utf-8`.